# Find the direction UISlider is pointing

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiview, uislider

I have a `UIView` class that contains a custom `UISlider`. When this `UIView` is added to a viewController it is randomly rotated using

```
newSlider.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(newSlider.transform, degreesToRadians(random));
```

Now what i'm trying to do is animate the `UISlider` thumb image flying off the end of the slider.
The problem i'm facing is getting the coordinates of the start/end of the slider so I can work out which way the thumb image is travelling.

I have tried using `trackRectForBounds` but it gives me the exact same coordinates regardless of the rotation applied to the `UIView`

I have tried these inside my `UIView` class:

```
CGRect trackRect = [customSlider trackRectForBounds:customSlider.bounds];
```

and

```
CGRect trackRect2 = [customSlider trackRectForBounds:self.window.bounds];
```

which give me {{2, 1}, {288, 50}} & {{2, 215}, {316, 50}} regardless of rotation. I think it's giving me the rect from within the `UIView` and not the screen.

Comment: Why is there once a `newSlider` and then `customSlider`?

Comment: newSlider is in my ViewController. It's basically the whole UIView class. MyCustomSliderView *newSlider
customSlider is inside that UIView class and refers to the UISlider thats added to the UIView.

Comment: No matter how the rect is rotated you will get it's origin and size - there's no rotational information included in bounds or frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the end-points of slider can be done like this:

[image]

```
CGFloat rotation = [[newSlider.layer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"] floatValue];

CGFloat halfWidth = newSlider.bounds.size.width/2;
CGPoint sliderCenter = newSlider.center;
sliderCenter.y += newSlider.bounds.size.height/2; //this shouldn't be needed but it seems it is

CGFloat x1 = sliderCenter.x - halfWidth * cos(rotation);
CGFloat x2 = sliderCenter.x + halfWidth * cos(rotation);

CGFloat y1 = sliderCenter.y - halfWidth * sin(rotation);
CGFloat y2 = sliderCenter.y + halfWidth * sin(rotation);

CGPoint T1 = CGPointMake(x1, y1);
CGPoint T2 = CGPointMake(x2, y2);
```

Comment: This would give me the rotation, but what I need is the rect. I can find out roughly which direction it's pointing, so if it's pointing up & right, I need the bottom/left coordinate, and the top/right coordinate so I can continue along the path between the two.

Comment: You have to know that rect is always defined with (x,y)(w,h) and not with (x1,y1)(x2,y2)(x3,y3)(x4,y4). So rect is always considered to be horizontally aligned. You could use the origin of the rect(x,y) and the direction to find out what you need.

Comment: I'm lost. If I check the UIView frame using NSLog(@"frame:%@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame)); it gets bigger as it's rotated, but the slider doesn't always run from corner to corner as the view has a background image too.

Comment: Yes. the frame is bigger because it holds the rotated view. Frame is always considered to be orthogonal (ie: width is horizontal, height vertical). Actually, if you rotate the view for 90° width will become height and height will become width.

Comment: Ok I understand that, so I can get the rect of the track as if it where horizontal and the rotation, but how can these give me the start/end points of the track based on the screen coordinates and not the rotated views coordinates?

Comment: There's a nice explanation here: http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/~jungle/555/notes/transforms.pdf (page 4). You can use the equations to calculate new positions of the border points.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a read through. Just looking at your drawing, that would be an easy examPle as the slider runs from corner to corner so easy to work out the path, if it was only say 25 degrees then the slider wouldn't be central of the view.

Comment: True, it shouldn't be too difficult. Of course it depends where you place your anchor = center of rotation. This can quickly make things a bit crazy :)

Comment: That's why I'm having trouble. I'm rotating on y so anchor should be in the centre but I just dont know the math to work it out. If I can get an x,y for the track start and end based on the full screen I'd be happy.

Comment: You have to set the anchor point before making the rotation? If you expand your question with a picture or two and some extra explanation i'm sure you'll get an answer. I'm going for today but could help you with the math tommorow (if you don't get response from others). Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help. Im actually having second thoughts on the animation I had planned so i'm going to shelve this for now. I might return to it at a later date. But thanks for your help.

Comment: @Darren: well, i was working on answer this morning so i'm updating the answer anyway :-)

Comment: Wow, i'm impressed :-) Thanks. I've just pasted the code in and it seems to give very usable coordinates. I will go ahead and continue my original plan and see how it pans out.
Thanks you.